# How do I use reflection to access an IEnumerable member within a type?

Tags: c#, reflection

How do I access IEnumerable members within a type.

In this case, the *Likes* property is never exposed in the *Retrieve* method of the *References* class.

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    // Setup
    var person          = new Person("some_id", "John", "Doe", new List<string>{ "Dogs" });
    var persons         = new List<Person> () { person };
    var valuePredicates = new List<Predicate<string>>() { v => v.EndsWith("Id") };

    // Test
    var references = References.Retrieve(person, new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>(), valuePredicates);
}
```

}

```
public static class References
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Retrieve(object obj, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> entries, IEnumerable<Predicate<string>> predicates)
    {
        var type = obj.GetType();

        if (type.IsPrimitive || type == typeof(string)) return entries;

        var structure = type.Name;

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties(
                    BindingFlags.GetProperty | 
                    BindingFlags.Public      | 
                    BindingFlags.Instance).Where(
                    x => x.CanRead &&
                    x.GetGetMethod(false) != null &&
                    x.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0))
        {
            var getMethod = property.GetGetMethod(true);

            if (getMethod != null)
            {
                foreach (var isPropertyOfName in predicates)
                {
                    if (isPropertyOfName(property.Name))
                    {
                        var identifier = $"{structure}::{property.Name}";
                        var textValue  = property.GetValue(obj) as string;
                        entries.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(identifier, textValue));
                    }
                }

                Retrieve(getMethod.Invoke(obj, null), entries, predicates);
            }
        }

        return entries;
    }
```

**Appendix:**

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string id, string firstName, string lastName, IEnumerable<string> likes) =>
        (Id, FirstName, LastName, Likes) = (id, firstName, lastName, likes);

    public string Id { get; }
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Likes { get; }
}
```

Comment: What do you get?  Are you stepping through the code or only inspecting the return value?

Comment: As I understand it, you're passing in a predicate which says "only return properties which end in `Id`" and `Likes` doesn't end with `Id`. Aside from that, you're also only fetching the value as a string: `var textValue  = property.GetValue(obj) as string;` An `IEnumerable<string>` isn't a string, so even if you *got* that far, `textValue` would be null.

Comment: As an aside, this code smacks of a lot of spooky action at a distance. Consider inverting responsibilities and using attributes to mark properties this code is supposed to be interested in, you'll need far less complicated reflection to get at those since it's their intended use case.

Comment: First change I recommend is to put the result of `type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)` into a named local variable, set a breakpoint between setting that variable and entering the foreach loop that walks it.  My guess is you will recurse on `System.Collections.Generic.List'1` but none of List's non-indexed properties are strings either.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: What if different callers are interested in different sets of properties?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Hence "consider". Sometimes code like this is unavoidable. At other times it's just people being unnecessarily clever ("it finds out what it needs, like magic!").